# Admin and User PHP Database login

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, session

I am pretty new to php coding and I have setup a working signup/signin system for a website, but now I want to create an admin user which can edit/upload pictures to the website. I just have no idea how to do it, so far I have just added a column to phpmyadmin which is usertype and its an enum with two variables which are admin and users, and I have set the default to user so when someone signs up they are defaulted as a user. so any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my login php

```
if (isset($_POST['login-submit'])) {
    #
require 'dbh.inc.php';

$mailuid = $_POST['mailuid'];
$password = $_POST['pwd'];

if (empty($mailuid) || empty($password)) {
    header("Location: ../index.php?error=emptyfields");
    exit();

}else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uidUsers=?;";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?error=sqlerror");
        exit();
    }else{

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $mailuid);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $pwdCheck = password_verify($password, $row['pwdUsers']);
            if ($pwdCheck == false) {
                header("Location: ../index.php?error=wrongpassword");
        exit();
            }elseif ($pwdCheck == true) {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['userId'] = $row['idUsers'];
                $_SESSION['userUid'] = $row['uidUsers'];

                header("Location: ../index.php?login=success");
                exit();

            }
        }
        else {
            header("Location: ../index.php?error=nouser");
        exit();
        }
    }

    }



}else {
    header("Location: ../index.php");
    exit();
}
```

This is my signup php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['signup-sumbit'])) {

    require 'dbh.inc.php';


    $username = $_POST['uid'];
    $email = $_POST['mail'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];
    $passwordRepeat = $_POST['pwd-repeat'];

    if (empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($passwordRepeat)) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=emptyfields&uid=".$username."&mail=".$email);
        exit();
    }elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invaildmailuid");
        exit();
    }elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invaildmail&uid=".$username);
        exit();
    }elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invailduid&mail=".$email);
        exit();
    }elseif ($password !== $passwordRepeat) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=passwordcheck&uid=".$username."&mail=".$email);
        exit(); 
    }else{
        $sql = "SELECT uidUsers FROM users WHERE uidUsers=?";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror1");
            exit();
        } else {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
            $resultCheck = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
            if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                header("Location: ../signup.php?error=usertaken&mail=".$email);
                exit();
            } else {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users (uidUsers, emailUsers, pwdUsers) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
                $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
                    exit();
                    } else {
                        $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);


                        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $username, $email, $hashedPwd);
                        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                        header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=success");
                        exit();
                    }




            }


        }



    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    mysqli_close($conn);


}else {
    header("Location: ../signup.php");
    exit();

}
```

This is a picture of the new column I added
[Picture of phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgWqO.jpg)

Comment: So what exactly is your question? You don't know how to use your `usertype` column? Or you don't know how to change the user account you wish to be an admin? Or you want to know how to use that `usertype` column in your code to display different content?

Comment: I am trying to display, different content depending on the usertype column, example if the user type is user I don't want them to be able to edit/upload photos, but if the user type is admin I want them to be able to edit/upload. I just don't know how to use usertype and check the usertype is user or admin.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code where you are checking if user has admin privileges and store in session

```
if($row['user_type'] == 'Admin'){
          $_SESSION['isAdmin'] = true;
}else{
          $_SESSION['isAdmin'] = false;
}
```

later you can use `$_SESSION['isAdmin']` to give privileges as you wish

```
if($_SESSION['isAdmin']){
//code for uploading pictuers ..
}
```

Comment: I have added it into my login code under where I check if the password is correct. and then added the other if statement to my html code, but I get undefined index.

Comment: When i login with my admin account the error goes away and i can see what i put in the code, when i normal user logs in the user can't see it, but when their is no user login in I get undefined index error

Comment: @marcus You need to check if user is logged in and based on that check if he is admin or not because your code check at the start if user is admin or not but nobody is logged so undefined happens